# Puppet exec unless doesn't appear to work how I expect

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to clone a db with exec from mysql, but I don't want to clone it if it has already been cloned.

```
exec { "clone_from_${name}" :
  unless => "/usr/bin/mysql -u${user_to} -p${pwd_to} ${name_to} -e'select count(*) from $test_table_name;' | grep -c ' 0 '",
...
```

The logic looks a little confusing but basically, the way I understand unless is that if the command returns a 0, then the whole exec wont be run. But it when I try it, it is.

The db has already been created in the vm, and if it's already been cloned, the count returned from the query gives me something other than a ' 0 ', and the grep because it doesn't find the ' 0 ' returns a 0. Unless should make it run then, right?

The output even gives me "Unless: 0"
and then "Executing

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the exitcode that is important, not the number that is printed.

If you run this command manually and do an `echo $?` afterwards, you get the exitcode.

Also, you want to surpress the output from the command:

```
exec { "clone_from_${name}" :
  unless => "/usr/bin/mysql -u${user_to} -p${pwd_to} ${name_to} -e'select count(*) from $test_table_name;' | grep ' 0 ' > /dev/null 2>&1",
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a > after ' 0 '?